# Ubuntu Compatible Hardware

Tags: hardware

Suppose, I want to buy a computer and install Ubuntu on it. I've found a tiny nettop with the following components:

```
        CPU: Intel Celeron
      Video: Intel HD
Motherboard: SoC
```

An expert who's selling it wasn't able to tell me whether it's be possible to install Ubuntu on that nettop.

**My question is:** looking at the computer components, is it possible to tell whether it's possible to install Ubuntu on it? Which components are crucial for that *(I think that it's only a CPU but I'm not sure)*?

*I think Intel Celeron is OK for Ubuntu but what about the motherboard? Does it make any difference that it is SoC (and not a usual motherboard we see in desktops)?*

Comment: Check the Minimum Requirements: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop. There are many iterations of Celeron, some will work, some won't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) If you're STILL not sure after that, choose vendors with a generous return policy.

Comment: @user535733, thank you for your prompt reply! Your link does answer my question.